# Lighttpd Port/Proxy Alias Redirect

Tags: lighttpd

I am trying to redirect an alias to an internal port.

[https]://www.site.com/place ---> [http]://localhost:10000

The configuration entry I currently have just changes the URL to [https]://www.site.com:10000 instead of preserving the URL.

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/place" {
  $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%0:10000" )
  }
}
```

I would like the URL to stay site.com/place

Answer (score 0):

Add $0 to the url

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/place" {
  $HTTP["host"] =~ ".*" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%0:10000$0" )
  }
}
```